# RabbitMQ Docker Bash Script Issue - .sh Not Found

Tags: bash, docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to create a RabbitMQ image that installs the `rabbitmq_auth_backend_http` plugin, and also executes a java application (`.jar`) via a `bash` script file.  However, when I run the container I get this output from RabbitMQ:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-deploy.sh: 2: /usr/local/bin/docker-deploy.sh: 
: not found

Starting rabbit-sidecar application

Enabling plugins on node rabbit@039e6bd1bbfd:

bbitmq_auth_backend_http

The following plugins have been configured:

  rabbitmq_auth_backend_http

  rabbitmq_management

  rabbitmq_management_agent

  rabbitmq_web_dispatch

Applying plugin configuration to rabbit@039e6bd1bbfd...

The following plugins have been enabled:

  rabbitmq_auth_backend_http

set 4 plugins.

Offline change; changes will take effect at broker restart.

/usr/local/bin/docker-deploy.sh: 4: /usr/local/bin/docker-deploy.sh: rabbitmq-server
: not found
```

It's also not finding `rabbitmq-server` which is needed to restart rabbit for the plugin to work.

To note, the java application appears to be working as it should and is just logging what it normally logs when its spun up as its own container.

Dockerfile

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.8.2-management

COPY ./rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

RUN apt -y update && apt -y install openjdk-8-jdk
RUN mkdir /sidecar
ADD ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /sidecar/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ./docker-deploy.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-deploy.sh
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/docker-deploy.sh #755
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/local/bin/docker-deploy.sh"]
```

Script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting rabbit-sidecar application"
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_backend_http; rabbitmq-server
# starts the sidecar
java -jar /sidecar/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My original custom image that worked was this:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.8.2-management

COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

CMD ["sh", "-c", "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_backend_http; rabbitmq-server"]
```

Which worked fine, but obviously I needed to do what I am doing because I want to be able to run another service within the same container as it requires it.

I did notice that there is a `docker-entrypoint.sh` in `/usr/local/bin`.  Is this something to be considered in this context?

Comment: Are you working on a Windows host?  Can you check that the script file has Unix line endings?  The (newline) `: not found` hints at this as a potential problem.

Comment: Indeed, there were carrige returns as well as line feeds.  I have rectified the problem with RabbitMQ but my Spring Java application will not execute now, which I imagine is a slightly different issue.